# Detaching a background process in zsh so that I can close the terminal

Tags: cygwin, zsh

I have a terminal process running zsh in the Cygwin environment. I want to start a background process and then close the terminal process and have the background process running. However, when I exit the terminal, I get the error message that it can't exit, because a background process is still running. Example:

```
sleep 300 &
exit
```

I get the message *zsh: you have running jobs.*

The same with

```
nohup sleep 300 &
```

From the man page of zsh, I see that there is a command called *disown* which, from the description, might do what I want, but I don't know how to use it. According to the man page, it expects an argument *job*, but doesn't say what this argument actually is. I tried

```
sleep 300 &
disown $!
```

but get the message *disown: job not found: 3964*, so a job is obviously not a PID.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: i don't think this is a possibility with cygwin you environment stop running the instant you close the window

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to refer to the job by it's job number

```
sleep 3000
control-z
bg
jobs
disown %3 (or whatever job number)
```

Comment: This works indeed. Since I want to do this from a shell function sourced by my .zshrc, it means that I have to parse the output from the *jobs* command. OK, not convenient, but can be done. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this still helps at lest other readers: `disown` without any parameter disconnects the job with job number `%1`.

In addition you might want to check out the [AUTO_CONTINUE on Ctrl-Z](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223433) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
alias bg='bg && disown'
```

in .zshrc to get bash-style behavior exiting terminal that launched process with keystrokes: `Ctrl + Z`, `bg`, `exit`